# My program is giving me a segmentation fault (c++)

Tags: c++, loops, file-io, fault

My program reads a text file line by line to get information about a group of people who have made donations.  It uses an array of structures to store the information (name, donation amount).  The first line of the text file is the number of contributors.  From then on the lines represent the name and value of a donation. eg:

```
3
Kyle Butler
10340
James Wright
5006
John Smith
10000
```

Then, if their donation is 10,000 or more, their name and donation value is outputted to the screen under the heading "grand patrons" otherwise, it appears under the heading "patrons"

The problem is, when i run the program, it gives me a segmentation fault with no evidence of the program outputting anything to the screen.  Can someone please tell me what is going on here?  I'm fairly new to the language.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstring>
#include <cctype>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

struct contribute {
    char Name[100];
    int contribution;
};

int main()
{

    char tempstore[100];
    int linecount=1;
    int pointerindex=0;
    ifstream inputfile("myfile.txt");

     if (!inputfile.is_open()){
         cout << "Error opening file";
     }

    inputfile.getline(tempstore, 20);
    int contributors = atoi(tempstore);
    contribute carray[contributors]; 

    while (!inputfile.eof()){
        if(linecount ==1){
            linecount++;
            continue;
        }

        inputfile.getline(tempstore, 20);


         if ((linecount % 2) == 0){
            strcpy( (carray[pointerindex]).Name, tempstore);

         }
         else {
             (carray[pointerindex]).contribution = atoi(tempstore);
         }


         ++linecount;
         ++pointerindex;
    }




    cout << "\n#####--#-Grand Patrons-#--#####\n";

    for (int i=0; i<contributors; i++){
        if (carray[i].contribution >= 10000){
            cout << "Name:  " << carray[i].Name << endl;
            cout << "Contribution:  " << carray[i].contribution << endl << endl;
        }
    }

    cout << "\n#####--#-Patrons-#--#####\n";

    for (int d=0; d<contributors; d++){
        if (carray[d].contribution < 10000){
            cout << "Name:  " << carray[d].Name << endl;
            cout << "Contribution:  " << carray[d].contribution << endl << endl;
        }
    }  

    inputfile.close();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What line is faulting?  Have you tried running it in a debugger?  What IDE, OS are you using?

Comment: contribute carray[contributors];  Your compiler let's you do this? Shouldn't it be contribute *carray = new contribute[contributers]; ?

Comment: @JonathanHenson 
No, this isn't a dynamic array, just an array of structures, i originally used a dynamic array but i thought that might be the reason behind the segfault so i changed to a static one.  Works either way.

Comment: My point is that will not compile on most compilers. Most will not allow you to create an array with a dynamic size without explicitly making it a dynamic array. Anyways, if it works it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're incrementing `pointerindex` on every pass through the loop, rather than just after you read in the contribution amounts. So by the time you get to reading in `5006`, you have `pointerindex == 3`, which causes a segfault on `carray[pointerindex]`.

Move `++pointerindex` into the `else` statement.

Comment: Thank you so much!  I knew it would be something simple and it suddenly makes so much sense!